# Android - в связи с прекращением существования системы, стоит ли изучать Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fuchsia

Как уже пишут, система Android в 2023-м году будет заменена на новую операционную систему, и все устройства уже будут выпускаться без Android.

Так как сегодня язык программирования Kotlin только начинает свое развитие, и многие библиотеки пока еще на Java, стоит ли браться за изучение Kotlin, если есть какой-то опыт в Java? Даже если в ближайшие 2-3 года Kotlin станет основным языком в Android программировании, каков будет смысл изучать его, если он вскоре не будет нужен?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что слухи о его близкой кончине сильно преувеличены... А стоит ли учить новые языки? Однозначно, да.

Comment: Вы что-то поспешили с выводами, не так всё просто. 
Kotlin не начинает своё развитие, он уже достаточно хорошо развит.
Однозначно стоит браться за изучение kotlin, потому что он востребован работодателями, вы увеличите свою значимость на фоне других кандидатов.
"Вскоре он будет не нужен"... ничего себе "вскоре", аж спустя 5 лет по предварительным оценкам

Comment: А про то что библиотеки пока ещё на джава, это никак вроде не должно мешать.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: И опять же, кто сказал что новая операционная система не будет поддерживать котлин? У котлина 3 версии:  Kotlin JVM, Kotlin JS and Kotlin Native. Я слышал что фуксия будет поддерживать JVM, значит наверное и котлин тоже будет поддерживаться.

Comment: гугл уже ChromeOS обещала все операционки "убьет" .. и где она .. с фуксией тоже никаких гарантий нет

Comment: 2023 уже скоро а фуксии все нет :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Даже если Android и будет заменен на Fuchsia или что-там еще, то надо четко понимать, что 70-80% успеха новой оси это наличие девелоперов, разработчиков под данную ось. Нет разработчиков - нет приложений, нет приложений нет оси. Уже многие пытались: HP выпускал [WebOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS), Samsung выпускал [Tizen](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen) и что? Где они теперь?

Если Google не сделает ставку на Java девелоперов - ось не взлетит.

Другой вопрос, что лет через 5 возможно появится другой язык программирования, который начнет доминировать. Сейчас многие активно пересаживаются на Kotlin, но надо понимать, что Kotlin это та же самая Java только в профиль, я вот лично Kotlin от Java почти не отделяю.

Следите за [рэнкингом языков](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html)

[image: PYPL ranking]

На мой пристрастный взгляд сейчас есть 2 перспективных языка: Python и Rust, первый потому что все вдруг резко увлеклись AI, ML и проч. модностями, а второй - ну не знаю, свежо как то :)

Answer (score 6):

Не факт, что Android будет заменен. Fucsia - пока только пробный проект.

Второе - обещали поддержку приложений из Google Play. Скорее всего, будет и поддержка Java-Kotlin приложений. А Kotlin в любом случае надо учить, даже если случится такое, что Fucsia выстрелит и программировать под нее будет нельзя на Kotlin`e, то в мире останется миллионы Android устройств. Да и пока ждешь до 2033-35 надо что-то делать...

Answer (score 2):

Как уже известно, готовящаяся на замену Android ОС Fuchsia будет базироваться на Flutter SDK. Недавно [вышла статья](https://tech.olx.com/fast-prototypes-with-flutter-kotlin-native-d7ce5cfeb5f1) на тему использования Kotlin c Flutter SDK. Пока не все гладко и есть существенные ограничения, но впереди еще пять лет и ответ на ваш вопрос по поводу нужности данного языка, думаю, очевиден.